# mysql cluster 7.4, crluster definition error

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I installed MySQL Cluster 7.4 and then I tried to define and start a new cluster. But after pressing create and start cluster the following error happened:
Command [u'net','start','N49'] returned non-zero exit status 2.
How to solve this error on MYSQL cluster 7.4?

I'm trying on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. My system didn't have enough memory for assignment then when I was choosing more memory for cluster configuration, in start time it encounter with mentioned exception.

Comment: Yup, had the same error message. When I lowered the memory settings it started. I just test it on my laptop, guess it is not the normal use case. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running the setup.bat as administrator.

Comment: partially fixed but Command '[u'net', 'start', 'N53']' returned non-zero exit status 2 error occured